# TestFlight: Email address privacy

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

Simple question: If I am invited to test a testflight app with email A@xyz.com, and my apple ID is B@xyz.com, which of the emails will the app developer see (when there is a crash report, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email that is seen is the one that the invite is sent to and not the Apple ID. Also, TestFlight does not connect user identifiers directly to crash reports. The data that a developer can see is whether the email they sent the invite to has accepted the invite, once accepted which is the latest build number the user has installed, how many total sessions the user has had, and a count of crashes (although in my experience this count is always empty).